# Is there a way to add dynamically new property inside an object which also add new property dynamically?

Tags: javascript

I need an object with property which I add dynamically and inside this property another one which I want to add dynamically too.

```js
const paths = ["POOL-p64/ld3/1/eee", "POOL-p64/ld3/1/afp_new"];
const peer = "EVO-Cluster-at-EVO-57";
const values = [
  {peer: "EVO-Cluster-at-EVO-57", path: "POOL-p64/ld3/1/eee", name: "14", isAllocated: false},
  {peer: "EVO-Cluster-at-EVO-57", path: "POOL-p64/ld3/1/afp_new", name: "3", isAllocated: false}
];

const objectINeeded = {};

paths.forEach(path => {
    objectINeeded[peer][path] = values.filter(brick => brick.isAllocated === false && brick.path===path)
  //another one works but don't add a new property just replace previous
  //objectINeeded[peer] = {
  //  [path] : values.filter(brick => brick.isAllocated === false && brick.path === path)
  //}
})

console.log(objectINeeded)
```

This is what I was looking for

```
{ 
  "EVO-Cluster-at-EVO-57": { 
    "POOL-p64/ld3/1/afp_new": [ 
      { 
        "peer": "EVO-Cluster-at-EVO-57", 
        "path": "POOL-p64/ld3/1/afp_new", 
        "name": "3", 
        "isAllocated": false 
      } 
    ], 
    "POOL-p64/ld3/1/eee": [ 
      { 
        "peer": "EVO-Cluster-at-EVO-57", 
        "path": "POOL-p64/ld3/1/eee", 
        "name": "14", 
        "isAllocated": false 
      } 
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You never did set the `objectINeed[peer] = {}` and thus you cannot access it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check the below code, we move the array values to object properties using a map, then finally resassign the structure to the same variable and get the output.

```js
const paths = ["POOL-p64/ld3/1/eee", "POOL-p64/ld3/1/afp_new"];
const peer = "EVO-Cluster-at-EVO-57";
const values = [
  {peer: "EVO-Cluster-at-EVO-57", path: "POOL-p64/ld3/1/eee", name: "14", isAllocated: false},
  {peer: "EVO-Cluster-at-EVO-57", path: "POOL-p64/ld3/1/afp_new", name: "3", isAllocated: false}
];
let out = {};
paths.map(function(x, i) {
  let value = values.filter(brick => brick.isAllocated === false && brick.path===x);
    out[x] = value ? [values[i]] : []
});
out = {[peer]: out}
console.log(out);
```

Comment: You are missing the filters

Comment: @yunzen this solution does not use `filter` maybe it can be done with the same, the end object structure is achieved with the current solution!

Comment: @NarenMurali I think the asker does want a little bit more than he is telling us. The example does not use any edge cases, mutliple appearances etc.

Comment: @yunzen have modified my answer to be more specific to the users question containing the filter condition, can you have check to be safe?

Comment: @yunzen yeah, I ended by myself, what I was looking for is this line `out = {[peer]: out}`

Comment: @yunzen case was totally different) I tried to bring simple example.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want .

I added some values to the original array to see more edge cases.

Two added objects should be filtered out (peer: `"EVO-Cluster-at-EVO-571"` and path: `"POOL-p64/ld3/1/eeea"`).

Also I added two objects, which share the same peer and path, so that they are pushed to the array of `objectINeeded[<peer>][<path>]`.

The result is an object with one peer key (`"EVO-Cluster-at-EVO-57"`) which has two path keys (`"POOL-p64/ld3/1/eee"` and `"POOL-p64/ld3/1/afp_new"`) of which the first one has two objects and the second one has only one object.

This is only a more generalized answer, as it allows for multiple peers

```js
console.clear()

const paths = [
  "POOL-p64/ld3/1/eee", 
  "POOL-p64/ld3/1/afp_new"
];
const peers = ["EVO-Cluster-at-EVO-57"];
const values = [
  {
    peer: "EVO-Cluster-at-EVO-57", 
    path: "POOL-p64/ld3/1/eeea", 
    name: "14", 
    isAllocated: false
  },
  {
    peer: "EVO-Cluster-at-EVO-571", 
    path: "POOL-p64/ld3/1/eee", 
    name: "14", 
    isAllocated: true
  },
  {
    peer: "EVO-Cluster-at-EVO-57", 
    path: "POOL-p64/ld3/1/eee", 
    name: "14", 
    isAllocated: false
  },
  {
    peer: "EVO-Cluster-at-EVO-57", 
    path: "POOL-p64/ld3/1/eee", 
    name: "15", 
    isAllocated: false
  },
  {
    peer: "EVO-Cluster-at-EVO-57", 
    path: "POOL-p64/ld3/1/afp_new", 
    name: "3", 
    isAllocated: false
  }
];

// Filter the original Array so that only those with the right properties are used
const filtered = values.filter(brick => (brick.isAllocated === false) 
                               && (paths.indexOf(brick.path) !== -1)
                               && (peers.indexOf(brick.peer) !== -1)
                              );

// 'Map' the filteres array to an object where the 'peer' and 'path' values are used as keys
const objectINeeded = filtered.reduce((map, obj, org) => {
  if (!map[obj.peer]) { map[obj.peer] =  {}; }
  if (!map[obj.peer][obj.path]) { map[obj.peer][obj.path] =  []; }
  map[obj.peer][obj.path].push({...obj});
  return map;
}, {});

console.log(objectINeeded)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
let objectINeeded2 = {};
objectINeeded2[peer] = {};
paths.forEach((x) => {
    objectINeeded2[peer][x] = values.filter(brick => brick.isAllocated === false && brick.path === x);
})
console.log(objectINeeded2);
```